# Does "git svn" command use any binaries/dlls to access a subversion server?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, visualsvn-server

After running **git svn fetch [remote]** command from my apache subversion server I see the incoming request user agent as **"SVN/1.9.3 (x86_64-pc-msys) serf/1.3.8"**.

I need to know **how git svn fetch command works**. I have already seen perl scripts (Ra.pm, SVN.pm...etc) but couldn't identify how git uses subversion tools or library to access subversion a repository.

The **subversion server and client (Git for windows 2.10.1)** are running on **windows**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git svn` shim ultimately relies on the Subversion's own client library and the libraries it depends on.

In my relatively dusty Git install these are named after `msys-svn_*.dll` and are located in the `usr\bin` directory under the root directory of the GfW installation.

Comment: Thanks @kostix for ponting me there.
Is their any way I could modify as per my need and rebuild the dll file and then replacing it would be sufficient ?